# How to read input on Play websocket server in Java?

Tags: java, playframework, websocket

My question is simply: How to read from Play's websockets in Java ? I need some method like readln() in normaln sockets. I know how to send anything to client, but i dont know how to read from client.

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from a book

> The **In** object `[WebSocket.In<String> in]` allows you to add
>   handlers to incoming events. To handle client messages,you can use the
>   following two methods by providing a callback handler:
>
> - onMessage()—This method calls the provided handler when a client    sends a message.
> - onClose()—This method calls the provided handler    when a client    closes its connection with the server.